# How to filter set of items from list of items - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two scope variables in angularJS. One storing "all the subcategories" and other storing "categories and their respective subcategories".

```
$scope.Categories = [
{
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "scname": "Sugar",
            "scid": "5"
        },
        {
            "scname": "Salt",
            "scid": "6"
        },
        {
            "scname": "Jaggery",
            "scid": "7"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Salt and Sugar",
    "id": "1",
    "image": "/images/salt_sugar.png"
},
{
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "scname": "Tea",
            "scid": "8"
        },
        {
            "scname": "Coffee",
            "scid": "9"
        },
        {
            "scname": "Tea Bags",
            "scid": "162"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Tea and Coffee",
    "id": "2",
    "image": "/images/tea_and_coffee.png"
}
]

$scope.subcategories = [
{
    "name": "Sugar",
    "id": "5"
},
{
    "name": "Salt",
    "id": "6"
},
{
    "name": "Jaggery",
    "id": "7"
},
{
    "name": "Tea",
    "id": "8"
},
{
    "name": "Coffee",
    "id": "9"
},
{
    "name": "Tea Bags",
    "id": "162"
}
]
```

On selecting a category i want to display mapped and unmapped subcategories with that particular category. First one is very easy. How to filter second  one? for example -

```
on selecting "Tea and Coffee" unmapped categories should be - Sugar, salt, Jaggery
on selecting "Salt and Sugar" unmapped categories should be - Tea, Coffee, Tea Bags
```

This is how I am listing mapped categories:

```
<TR align="center">
    <TD>
        <select ng-options="c as c.name for c in Categories|orderBy:'name' " ng-model="selectedCategory" size="10"> </select>
    </TD>

    <TD>
        <select ng-options="sc as sc.scname for sc in selectedCategory.subcategories|orderBy:'scname' " ng-model="SelectedMappedSubCategory" size="10"> </select>
    </TD>


    <TD>
        <select ng-options="sc as sc.name for sc in SubCategories | orderBy:'name' | ???????" ng-model="SelectedUnMappedSubCategory" size="10"> </select>
    </TD>
</tr>
```

What logic should I use in-place if ?????????

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, why not just filter it?

```
| filter: {scname: SelectedUnMappedSubCategory.scname}
```

EDIT:

I can see that you edited the code you originally posted. I think you can achieve what you are trying to do, by this:

```
| filter: {id: SelectedUnMappedSubCategory.scid}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this suggested solution. But this is filtering all the data, means "No Data" left to show after using this.

Comment: How can we filter the items using same ng-model, for which we are trying to filter? What is the value of SelectedUnMappedSubCategory.scid, when we are trying to filter? Can you please explain the logic for your answer?

Comment: We need to filter all the subcategories those are in selectedCategory.subcategories, so just wanted to understand why you using SelectedUnMappedSubCategory for filter?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just change it to SelectedMappedSubCategory then?

Comment: In that case it will filter only one single SelectedMappedSubCategory. Because SelectedMappedSubCategory will hold only 1 subcategory (selected one). I want to filter against set of subcategories not only one subcategory?

Answer (score 0):

Create a customized filter:

```
sampleApp.filter('filterSubcategories', function() {
return function(input, filterkey) {
    var filtered = [];
    if (filterkey) {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            var item = input[i];
            var found = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < filterkey.length; ++j) { 
                if (item.id == filterkey[j].scid) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found){
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered;
};
});
```

and use this like:

```
<TD>
     <select ng-options="sc as sc.name for sc in SubCategories |  filterSubcategories:selectedCategory.subcategories | orderBy:'name'" ng-model="SelectedUnMappedSubCategory" size="10"> </select>
</TD>
```